# Slow instantiation of a COM server in WPF App constructor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

I have a WPF application targeting net7.0-windows.
It is also a Prism app with Unity container.
I need to register a COM out-of-process server (e.g. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application).
Doing this with `containerRegistry.RegisterInstance(new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application());` takes about 7-8 seconds.
I certainly don't understand what's going on during this long time, but if my registration is done like this: `Task.Run(() => containerRegistry.RegisterInstance(new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application())).Wait();` it is pretty fast and dependency injection seems to be working just fine.

Question 1: What is going on during the long time need to do the       registration synchronous (the "normal" way)?
Question 2: Is there any    caveats in doing it the asynchronous way by a Task and Wait?

Comment: `Wait` is not asynchronous - it blocks. Other than that the `Task.Run` runs your code on a threadpool thread, they are exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for wrong terms re. async. What do you mean by "exactly the same"? Performance is very different if running in task or not

Comment: are you sure that the threadpool variant actually works? if I remember correctly, you have to do com stuff from a sta thread. it _might_ be fast in the threadpool thread because it just aborts without actually starting excel.

Comment: I used excel as an example (which I need later anyway), so haven't tried any operations on it in VM which get it delivered by unity container. However, my real COM object seems to work just fine in the VM. Haven't gried all methods etc. (hundreds), but just a few which all behave well